# HTML DIV Button Positioning

Tags: css, html, button, position

I am trying to accomplish something simple which is surprisingly taking awhile to figure out. I am very new to HTML/CSS/JSP. All I would like to do is create a div on the left side of the screen to contain 8 buttons and a div on the right side of the page to contain another 8 buttons.

```
<%!int buttonWidth=250;
int buttonHeight=75;%>

<style type="text/css">
    .button {color:blue; 
             font-size: large; 
             width:<%=(buttonWidth+"px")%>; 
             height:<%=(buttonHeight+"px")%>}

    #TVs {top:0px; 
           left: 0px; 
           width: <%=(buttonWidth*2+"px")%>;
           height: <%=(buttonHeight*8)+"px"%>;
           postion: absolute; 
           border: 2px solid green}

    #Sources {top:0; 
            left: <%=(buttonWidth*3+"px")%>; 
            width: <%=(buttonWidth*2+"px")%>;
            height: <%=(buttonHeight*8)+"px"%>;
            postion: absolute; 
            border: 2px solid red}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<h2>Poseidon TV Control</h2>
<hr/>

<div id="TVs"> 
     <button id="TV1" class="button">TV1</button>
     <button id="TV2" class="button">TV2</button> 
</div>

<div id="Sources"> 
     <button id="DISH1" class="button">DISH1</button>
     <button id="DISH2" class="button">DISH2</button> 
</div>
```

The div containers appear on top of eachother, both aligned on the left side of the screen. This confuses me as all the other style elements are working (color of border, width, etc.) I have a feeling there is an easy fix, so if someone could please help this beginner I'd be very appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: Mistype in CSS. `postion: absolute;` should be `position: absolute;`. Also you should add `right: 0;` to `#Sources`.

Comment: ah wow. knew it was an easy fix.. cant believe I didn't see that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if you used Float for the divs (you need to make sure you clear the float when you're done):

```
<%!int buttonWidth=250;
int buttonHeight=75;%>

<style type="text/css">
    .button {color:blue; 
             font-size: large; 
             width:<%=(buttonWidth+"px")%>; 
             height:<%=(buttonHeight+"px")%>}

    #TVs { 
           width: <%=(buttonWidth*2+"px")%>;
           height: <%=(buttonHeight*8)+"px"%>;
           border: 2px solid green};
           float:left;

    #Sources { 
            width: <%=(buttonWidth*2+"px")%>;
            height: <%=(buttonHeight*8)+"px"%>;
            float:left;
            margin-left:<%=(buttonWidth*3+"px")%>;
            border: 2px solid red}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<h2>Poseidon TV Control</h2>
<hr/>

<div id="TVs"> 
     <button id="TV1" class="button">TV1</button>
     <button id="TV2" class="button">TV2</button> 
</div>

<div id="Sources"> 
     <button id="DISH1" class="button">DISH1</button>
     <button id="DISH2" class="button">DISH2</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want Sources on the right side of the screen

```
#Sources {top:0; 
            right: <%=(buttonWidth*3+"px")%>; 
            width: <%=(buttonWidth*2+"px")%>;
            height: <%=(buttonHeight*8)+"px"%>;
            postion: absolute; 
            border: 2px solid red}
```